# Rails 3: How to move code from view to controller (or model)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in the `index` view:

```
<% @submissions.each do |submission| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= submission.id %></td>
        <td><%= User.find_by_id(submission.user_id).name.to_s %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I know I am not supposed to use `find_by` in the view.

How can I move this to the controller (or model)?

I tried to insert this in the `index` method of my `submission` controller and using the `username` variable but it doesn't work.

```
def index
    @submissions = Submission.all
    @submissions.each do |submission|
      username = User.find_by_id(submission.user_id).name.to_s
    end
end
```

Comment: You have a N+1 problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model, add relation to user

```
class Submission
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller, eager load users to avoid N+1 queries.

```
def index
  @submissions = Submission.includes(:user).all
end
```

View, just project the user from each submission

```
<% @submissions.each do |submission| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= submission.id %></td>
        <td><%= submission.user.name.to_s %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can I also use this approach on another model `type` when `submission` `has_many` `types`?

Comment: Yes, you can. In that case you will have many 'types', and you will need iterate them.

Comment: Thank you, in my case, I just use `submission` `has_one` `type` since I only have one type for each submission. Another question though: my `submission` model `belongs_to` another model `base`, but the `base` model uses a different table name `self.table_name = submission_bases`. When I try to do the something like `user`, it doesn't work anymore, in my view I used `submission.base` but it cannot recognize the model `base`. In my `submissions` table I have a foreign key `submission_base_id`

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem: need to set: `belongs_to :base, :foreign_key => :submission_base_id`

Answer (score 2):

```
#in controller
def index
  @submissions = Submission.all
end

#in view
<% @submissions.each do |submission| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= submission.id %></td>
        <td><%= submission.user.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

This code implies you have declared the following relations:

- Submission `belongs_to :user`
- User `has_many :submissions` (or has_one)

You can use eager loading (uses less queries to the DB) to improve the previous code:

```
@submissions = Submission.includes(:user).all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ActiveRecord association:

```
class Submission
  belongs_to :user

  # etc
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<td><%= submission.id %></td>
<td><%= submission.user.first_name</td> <!-- or whatever -->
```